# attempted relative import beyond top-level package message in PyCharm only

Tags: python, pycharm, python-3.7

UPDATE: if I change the name of the `select` module (in which the import error occurs) to `select1`, the problem goes away! WHAT the?

First off: everything works fine when I try to import my package from the command line, or run pytest in the project directory.

But in PyCharm I'm getting the "attempted relative import beyond top-level package" problem when I try to run my tests, and ONLY while in PyCharm. I can't figure out why.

I have even deleted and re-cloned the repository and the problem still occurs.

Here is the [link](https://github.com/Ricyteach/candejar/tree/select.by_shape) to the problem branch.

And here is the tb:

```
Testing started at 4:02 PM ...
C:\Users\ricky\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.2\helpers\pycharm\_jb_pytest_runner.py" --path C:/Users/ricky/PycharmProjects/candejar/tests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.2\helpers\pycharm\_jb_pytest_runner.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import iter_entry_points
  File "C:\Users\ricky\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "C:\Users\ricky\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\email\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "C:\Users\ricky\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email._policybase import compat32
  File "C:\Users\ricky\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\email\_policybase.py", line 9, in <module>
    from email.utils import _has_surrogates
  File "C:\Users\ricky\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\email\utils.py", line 29, in <module>
    import socket
  File "C:\Users\ricky\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 52, in <module>
    import os, sys, io, selectors
  File "C:\Users\ricky\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\selectors.py", line 12, in <module>
    import select
  File "C:\Users\ricky\PycharmProjects\candejar\candejar\select.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import exc
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm sure there is something simple going on here but I just can't figure it out. NOTE: I'm using Python 3.7 RC 1.

The `sys.path` in pycharm and the command line come out to be the same, except pycharm also includes the pycharm project main package directory (which for some reason appears *twice*).

Comment: Check if your `sys.path` is different when running from console and from PyCharm.

Comment: @Norrius the `sys.path` lists are identical except the pycharm project includes the project main package directory at the end. an empty string also appears at the front of the command line version.

Comment: As to the edit: [`select`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html) is a standard module in Python, which might affect imports.

Comment: @Norrius huh- i didn't know that it was part of the stdlib. but it was working fine before. and now i have deleted the `.idea` directory and that seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by deleting the `.idea` directory from the cloned repository and re-opening PyCharm. I still don't know what was wrong, but it is fixed now. Very weird.

UPDATE: it has something to do with the following line in the project `.iml` file in the `.idea` folder:

```
<sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/candejar" isTestSource="false" />
```

Removing that xml code solves the issue. But I do not know why, and I don't know how it got there in the first place (I do not recall messing around with any of my settings prior to this error).